# GitBash : Set Prompt to $

Tags: linux, windows, bash, directory, git-bash

I am new to programming and have this simple question about GitBash on my Windows 11 machine. I would like to see the `$` only on prompt. How do I modify that so it looks simple and clean?

My current bash prompt looks like:

```bash
mbaaq@AsusVivoBook:~/OneDrive/Desktop$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the prompt to '$ ' by typing `PS1='$ '`, or to set it that way on login, `echo "PS1='$ '" >> ~/.bashrc && . ~/.bashrc`. Which adds an entry to the [bashrc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work) file, which gets loaded when bash starts.